# How to implement real-time interaction with a virtual Android device and transfer sound and image?

Tags: android, websocket, virtual-machine, emulation, ui-virtualization

I am developing an Android app in Kotlin that provides access to a virtual Android device hosted on a server. The virtual device is running Android OS, and the user interacts with it through their own Android device.

My main challenge is how to implement real-time interaction and transfer of sound and image between the virtual device and the user's device. Specifically, I need to be able to share the virtual device's screen, capture user input (touch events) from their Android device and simulate them on the virtual device, and transfer audio in real-time from the virtual device to the user's device.

Basically I need to create some kind of AnyDesk android copy. I will be glad of any help, if I need to improve my question, also write about that!

Now I'm just looking for ways how to do this, my first thought was about transferring events through WebSockets, but I'm not sure if I will be able to transfer touch events and screen real-time